# How to get all the pixel values within the particular shape(ellipse, square) or within the particular coordinate range?

Tags: opencv, contour

I had drawn an ellipse that need to be marked as ROI. In that ROI, person detection needs to be implemented. I don't know how to mark that ellipse shape as ROI, so I decided to get all the pixel values of the ellipse to compare with the pixel value of the person's bounding box for better alerts.

Anyone help me to sort this out.

Comment: This is often solved by masks: Draw the ellipse filled on a new 1-channel image. Now for any point you want to check, you can get the pixel from the mask and decide whether it is 0 or > 0

Comment: @Micka isn't there a function which checks any pixel inside a given contour or not ? I believe there was but couldnt remember.

Comment: This gives me some idea, Thankyou.

Comment: we are getting pixel value in BGR [a,b,c] format. how to get max and min radii of an ellipse to compare with the point using math formula in opencv??

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk afaik there is a pointInPolygon test in opencv. The lookup table (a mask) is typically faster (while needing more memory), but it depends on the number of regions and the number of tests which are performed per region.